# I think stopPropagation() is breaking my mouse events - how can I fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect clicks anywhere on the document **only after** my start session button has been clicked. The start session button adds a `.waiting` class to the `body`.

I have used `stopPropagation()`, but I think this is breaking some `mouseover/mouseout` functionality that adds a hover state class to child elements.

The issue is that once the both the session button and document has been clicked, `mouseover/mouseout` functionality still happens despite removal of the `.waiting` class.

What is the solution to fix my code please? Or, is `stopPropagation()` a bad idea for my use case given **[this article](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)**.

There is a snippet below - just click the button, hover over the squares and then click. The problem is the squares still have red outline on hover.

```js
$("#start-session").on("click", function(e) {
  $("body").addClass("waiting");

  $("body.waiting").children().mouseover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".el-hover").removeClass("el-hover");
    $(e.target).addClass("el-hover");
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    $(e.target).removeClass("el-hover");
  });

  e.stopPropagation();
})

$(document).on("click", function(e) {

  if ($("body").hasClass("waiting")) {

    e.preventDefault()

    alert("Document was clicked");
    $("body").removeClass("waiting")
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  background: stealblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 50px;
}

.zone {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}

.el-hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start-session">Start session</button>

<div id="container">
  <div class="zone"></div>
  <div class="zone"></div>
  <div class="zone"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: stopPropagation is bad, yes. And your problem would probably not even need fixing, but dissolve into complete non-existence, if you weren’t for some reason using JavaScript for stuff that CSS can handle perfectly fine (talking about the hover effect here.)

Comment: @CBroe The hover effect is applicable to any child element of the body when the body itself has a class of `.waiting`. Is that really possible in CSS?

Comment: `body.waiting .whatever:hover { ... }`

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately it needs to be a wildcard type selector as I need to target every element on the page, and the DOM structure will not always be the same. I tried `body.waiting *:hover { ... }` but it didn't work.

Comment: Well `*:hover` doesn’t make that much sense to begin with, because that would apply for every element in the chain (meaning, hovering one of your `.zone` elements automatically means hovering `#container` at the same time, and so forth.)

Comment: @CBroe That is why I opted to JS to achieve the hover. Regarding `stopPropagation()` is there an alternative approach that will do what I need?

Comment: `$("body.waiting").children().mouseover(...)` applies the handler to all elements found at the time - the handler does not magically get removed, once body loses that class again. You’re trying to work against that by stopping propagation, but I think you’d be better off applying the handler only if that class is _currently_ present to begin with. Using event delegation you could achieve that kind of “dynamism” - but for that you would have to go one level up here, so that you can use body in the selector - something like `$(document).on('mouseover', 'body.waiting *', function(...) {})`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

To quote @CBroe from the comments:

> `$("body.waiting").children().mouseover(...)` applies the handler to all elements found at the time - the handler does not magically get removed, once body loses that class again. You’re trying to work against that by stopping propagation, but I think you’d be better off applying the handler only if that class is currently present to begin with. Using event delegation you could achieve that kind of “dynamism” - but for that you would have to go one level up here, so that you can use body in the selector - something like `$(document).on('mouseover', 'body.waiting *', function(...) {})`

**Updated snippet**

```js
$("#start-session").on("click", function(e) {
  $("body").addClass("waiting");

  $(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).css({
        "outline": "1px solid red"
      })
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).css({
        "outline": "0"
      })
    }
  }, 'body.waiting *');

  e.stopPropagation();
})

$(document).on("click", function(e) {

  if ($("body").hasClass("waiting")) {

    e.preventDefault()

    alert("Document was clicked");
    $("body").removeClass("waiting")
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  background: stealblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 50px;
}

.zone {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}

.el-hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start-session">Start session</button>

<div id="container">
  <div class="zone"></div>
  <div class="zone"></div>
  <div class="zone"></div>
</div>
```